# Download apt get to a repo

Tags: linux-mint, redhat-enterprise-linux, apt

is there a possibility to download all the packages i need to a specific repo which i could bring it to another offline linux system.

I would need to download apt get packages in Linux mint and transfer them to a Redhat linux distribution on a LAN.

Let me rephrase my question.

I have a linux mint OS currently which i would need to download some packages.

After downloading these packages, i would like to store them in a repo or a folder which i could copy this entire folder/repo into a redhat linux OS. This OS is on a LAN with no internet access. How would i be able to achieve this?

Comment: Is this kind of what you are looking for? [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/531403/how-to-download-all-repository-using-apt-get)

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Not really. I rephrased my questions. Thanks

Comment: Just how exactly are you planning to use Mint packages on Red Hat, anyway?

Comment: They are just some python packages that i need

Answer (score 0):

### The answer to your question

If you want to get the deb files needed for an installation, you can download-only on the internet pc and recover / copy them later :

```sh
apt update
rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*
apt install --download-only software_name
mkdir ~/packages
cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*deb ~/packages
```

---

**WARNING**: It seems like a good solution but be careful, if you want to be able to copy paste the deb files and have a successful installation you will need to have an almost exact copy of the target system in order to download the files. Otherwise missing packages, kernel version errors, etc. will occurs.

---

### The proper way to do it: `apt-offline`

The real good way of installing packages on an offline system is to use `apt-offline`. It as really few dependencies allowing you to install it on the offline system with `dpkg -i`.
Download the deb file on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=apt-offline).

Example :

```bsh
# Online is the computer connected to internet
# Offline is the computer disconnected from internet
# ---
# ## Install apt-offline ## 
# Online
apt update
apt install apt-offline

# ## Update System ##
# Offline
apt-offline set --update updates.sig
# Online
apt-offline get updates.sig --bundle updates.zip
# Offline 
apt-offline install updates.zip

# ## Upgrade System ##
# <!> Update must be done before.
# Offline
apt-offline set --upgrade upgrade.sig
# Online
apt-offline get upgrade.sig --bundle upgrades.zip
# Offline 
apt-offline install upgrades.zip
apt upgrade --no-download --fix-missing

# ## Install packages##
# <!> Update must be done before.
# pkg1, pkg2 & pkg3 being the packages you want to install
# Offline 
apt-offline set install.sig --install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
# Online
apt-offline get install.sig --bundle install.zip
# Offline 
apt-offline install install.zip
apt install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 --no-download --fix-missing
```

**Important**: Do not proceed to the update and upgrade/install at the same time. By doing so the upgrade is performed from the package list already installed on the computer, not after the update.

**Important 2**: `apt-offline install` and `upgrade` are not enough to get the packages installed. The only thing this command do, is to fill up the cache of apt (`/var/cache/apt/archives`) with the packages. That allows you to proceed with `apt install --no-download --fix-missing`.